# How to validate Combo selected value (character) range

Tags: vb.net

I'm getting value from combo. I want to check its selected value is greater than 01 and less than 05.

following my sample example

If (cboPaymentMethod.SelectedItem.ToString.Substring(0, (cboPaymentMethod.SelectedItem).ToString.IndexOf("-")).ToString.Trim.ToUpper) > "01" and (cboPaymentMethod.SelectedItem.ToString.Substring(0, (cboPaymentMethod.SelectedItem).ToString.IndexOf("-")).ToString.Trim.ToUpper) < "05" then

Process

End If

Comment: First, make the code simpler by making a separate variable for `(cboPaymentMethod.SelectedItem).ToString.IndexOf("-"))`. Then tell us what goes wrong, e.g. any value is accepted, no values are accepted, or something else.

Comment: Dear Andrew, I want to know how to validate character range. Such as Combo Result > "01" and < "05" like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is usually better to split code into separate parts instead of doing it all in one line. It makes it easier to see what is happening and avoids redundancy.

It looks like you have the right idea, but perhaps somewhere in all that jumble there is a problem, so let us re-write it like this:

```
If cboPaymentMethod.SelectedIndex >= 0 Then
    Dim itm = cboPaymentMethod.SelectedItem.ToString()
    Dim dashPos = itm.IndexOf("-")

    If dashPos >= 0 Then
        Dim num = itm.Substring(0, dashPos).Trim()

        If num > "01" AndAlso num < "05" Then
            MsgBox("In range")
        End If

    End If

End If
```

Where the MsgBox is there just for testing quickly.